# water heater keeps on turning off

Tags: plumbing, gas, hot-water

my water heater (gas Rheem MODEL NO.42VP75FW) keeps on shutting off [image]

this is the error code it shows[image]

it means the maximum amount of ignations attempt have been made and the system has went into lockdown mode

when i turn it off, wait a little, and turn it back on the system works for around 10 minutes (heating up  the water) before locking up again.
what am i supossed to do ?
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the ignitor can't ignite.  I'm not sure if it can't ignite the main burner or a pilot light that also shuts off between cycles.  If you familiar with such thing you might attempt cleaning yourself. However because you had to ask this question, it might be better to get a professional since gas appliances can potentially blow up and cause fire.   Also you should post the exact model number, we can't get very specific with info otherwise, post general info, like you have, and you get general answers.

Comment: What's the make and model of the tank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling Rheem customer service, I was told I must replace the entire control unit which controls the igniter.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tyson, some ignighters are powered and have something that look like a coil around an insulator. Some look like a flat black plate with lines cut through them and the last is a pilot , all of these can fail with a dirty burner or a bad thermocouple safety. A pro may be needed but if you read up on these types of ignition sources you may be able to DIY and save a bunch.

Comment: can you explain why it works for the first 10 minutes

Comment: If the flame is not directly on the thermocouple it may be shutting down for safety.